# How do you get clients name,and put it into a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to get the messengers name, place it into text and send it to a channel, with my discord.js bot.

I have already tried doing `${user}` but that gave an error message.

```
if (msg.content !== last) {
  last = msg.content;
  client.channels.get("531281263261253682").send(`${user}, sent ` + last);
}
```

The results I want is for it to send:
*'Username' has sent 'message'*

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming you are trying to get the author of the message. If that is the case, try this:

```
client.channels.get("531281263261253682").send(msg.author.username + ", sent " +  last);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `user` variable doesn't exist by default, so unless you declared it by yourself it will not be usable.
The author of the message is stored in [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author): since it is a User, you can choose what to display:

- To display only the username: `.username`
- To display the tag (`name#1234`): `.tag`
- To get the mention (`@name`) simply pass the author object, the [`.toString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString) method will be called automatically

Here's an example in your situation:

```
if (msg.content !== last) {
  last = msg.content;
  client.channels.get("531281263261253682").send(`${msg.author} sent ${last}`);
}
```